# Parsing XML using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, twitter-bootstrap

Having trouble parsig [xml](/questions/tagged/xml)using [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax). Can't seem to see what's going wrong here, as I have been able to retrieve API's using [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)elsewhere in my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**[html](/questions/tagged/html):**

```
<div id="technology" class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3>TECH</h3>
  <p id="tech_news"></p>
</div>
```

**[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery):**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/technology/rss.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    cache: false,
    success: parseXml
  });
});

function parseXml(xml) {
  $(xml).find("item").each(function() {
    $("#tech_news").append($(this).find("title").text() + "<p>");
    $("#tech_news").append($(this).find("description").text() + "<p>");
  });
}
```

Comment: can you share the response `xml`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I'm not sure what you mean? Sorry.

Comment: you have specified `dataType:"XML"` which means it returns an `XML` document that can be processed via jQuery. I am talking about that response document

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam The XML file is specified in the url above. It is an RSS feed from a news site.

Comment: Failed to load https://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/technology/rss.xml?_=1511718738881: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access`.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez Would it not allow you to access?

Comment: @KaliMa See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have a [cors](/questions/tagged/cors)issue. We have this error message:

> Failed to load
>   http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/technology/rss.xml?_=1511718738881: `No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access`.

However you can use this service https://crossorigin.me/ to allow cross origins requests through [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax).

Something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://crossorigin.me/http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/technology/rss.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    cache: false,
    success: parseXml
  });
});

function parseXml(xml) {
  $(xml).find("item").each(function() {
    $("#tech_news").append($(this).find("title").text() + "<p>");
    $("#tech_news").append($(this).find("description").text() + "<p>");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="technology" class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3>TECH</h3>
  <p id="tech_news"></p>
</div>
```

Even so, you should know that it is an external service that may not be operational 24/7.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. However, I'm intrigued as to how it actually works? What does https://crossorigin.me actually do?

Just want to know so it can assist me in future work :)

Comment: Oh you're welcome. It´s a **CORS** proxy. It's a service that allows developers to access resources from other websites, without having to own that website. Just adding 'http://crossorigin.me' to the beginning of any url which has no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* ` in the response headers.